# Discord cogs main.py :54: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.load_extension' was never awaited bot.load_extension(extension)

Tags: discord, discord.py

Помогите пожалуйста хотел создать бота для прослушивания музыки через коги но вылетает 2 ошибки

```
C:\...\main.py:54: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.load_extension' was never awaited
  bot.load_extension(extension)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Как вставил коги:

```
cogs = ["music_cog"]


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    for extension in cogs:
        bot.load_extension(extension)
        print('oki!')
    print('Bot online!')
```

А вот сам ког(его я нашел на гитхабе):

```
from ast import alias
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL


class music_cog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

        # all the music related stuff
        self.is_playing = False
        self.is_paused = False

        # 2d array containing [song, channel]
        self.music_queue = []
        self.YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio', 'noplaylist': 'True'}
        self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5',
                               'options': '-vn'}

        self.vc = None

    # searching the item on youtube
    def search_yt(self, item):
        with YoutubeDL(self.YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            try:
                info = ydl.extract_info("ytsearch:%s" % item, download=False)['entries'][0]
            except Exception:
                return False

        return {'source': info['formats'][0]['url'], 'title': info['title']}

    def play_next(self):
        if len(self.music_queue) > 0:
            self.is_playing = True

            # get the first url
            m_url = self.music_queue[0][0]['source']

            # remove the first element as you are currently playing it
            self.music_queue.pop(0)

            self.vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(m_url, **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=lambda e: self.play_next())
        else:
            self.is_playing = False

    # infinite loop checking
    async def play_music(self, ctx):
        if len(self.music_queue) > 0:
            self.is_playing = True

            m_url = self.music_queue[0][0]['source']

            # try to connect to voice channel if you are not already connected
            if self.vc == None or not self.vc.is_connected():
                self.vc = await self.music_queue[0][1].connect()

                # in case we fail to connect
                if self.vc == None:
                    await ctx.send("Could not connect to the voice channel")
                    return
            else:
                await self.vc.move_to(self.music_queue[0][1])

            # remove the first element as you are currently playing it
            self.music_queue.pop(0)

            self.vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(m_url, **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=lambda e: self.play_next())
        else:
            self.is_playing = False

    @commands.command(name="play", aliases=["p", "playing"], help="Plays a selected song from youtube")
    async def play(self, ctx, *args):
        query = " ".join(args)

        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        if voice_channel is None:
            # you need to be connected so that the bot knows where to go
            await ctx.send("Connect to a voice channel!")
        elif self.is_paused:
            self.vc.resume()
        else:
            song = self.search_yt(query)
            if type(song) == type(True):
                await ctx.send(
                    "Could not download the song. Incorrect format try another keyword. This could be due to playlist or a livestream format.")
            else:
                await ctx.send("Song added to the queue")
                self.music_queue.append([song, voice_channel])

                if self.is_playing == False:
                    await self.play_music(ctx)

    @commands.command(name="pause", help="Pauses the current song being played")
    async def pause(self, ctx, *args):
        if self.is_playing:
            self.is_playing = False
            self.is_paused = True
            self.vc.pause()
        elif self.is_paused:
            self.is_paused = False
            self.is_playing = True
            self.vc.resume()

    @commands.command(name="resume", aliases=["r"], help="Resumes playing with the discord bot")
    async def resume(self, ctx, *args):
        if self.is_paused:
            self.is_paused = False
            self.is_playing = True
            self.vc.resume()

    @commands.command(name="skip", aliases=["s"], help="Skips the current song being played")
    async def skip(self, ctx):
        if self.vc != None and self.vc:
            self.vc.stop()
            # try to play next in the queue if it exists
            await self.play_music(ctx)

    @commands.command(name="queue", aliases=["q"], help="Displays the current songs in queue")
    async def queue(self, ctx):
        retval = ""
        for i in range(0, len(self.music_queue)):
            # display a max of 5 songs in the current queue
            if (i > 4): break
            retval += self.music_queue[i][0]['title'] + "\n"

        if retval != "":
            await ctx.send(retval)
        else:
            await ctx.send("No music in queue")

    @commands.command(name="clear", aliases=["c", "bin"], help="Stops the music and clears the queue")
    async def clear(self, ctx):
        if self.vc != None and self.is_playing:
            self.vc.stop()
        self.music_queue = []
        await ctx.send("Music queue cleared")

    @commands.command(name="leave", aliases=["disconnect", "l", "d"], help="Kick the bot from VC")
    async def dc(self, ctx):
        self.is_playing = False
        self.is_paused = False
        await self.vc.disconnect()

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(music_cog(bot))
```

Прошу помочь!

Answer (score 1):

bot.load_extension - асинхронная функция, значит вызывать её нужно с await:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    for extension in cogs:
        await bot.load_extension(extension)
        print('oki!')
    print('Bot online!')
```

Помимо этого, вы нигде не создаёте объект кога, попробуйте так:

```
# Импорт класса music_cog (возможно, будет немного отличаться)
from music_cog import music_cog 

cogs = [music_cog(bot)]  # список объектов когов
@bot.event async def on_ready(): 
    for extension in cogs: 
        await bot.add_cog(extension)
        print('oki!')
    print('Bot online!')
```

Comment: сделал как вы написали

Ошибка:


[2022-12-24 14:06:03] [ERROR   ] discord.client: Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 946, in _load_from_module_spec
    await setup(self)
TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (...):
  ....
discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'music_cog' raised an error: TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression

Comment: изменил ответ, попробуйте

Comment: ошибка:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandRegistrationError: The command clear is already an existing command or alias.
ed: Extension 'music_cog' raised an error: TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression